# Does Bash ignore # after command?

Tags: linux, bash, comments

I know that Bash ignores the `#` character at the beginning of shell script lines. But in documentation I'd like to add them at the end of lines for documentation:

```
ls -l #long directory listing
```

Just in case somebody copies and pastes the literal information I've written, will Bash ignore everything after the `#` character? For every command? (It seems to work in informal testing, but a reference to some definitive answer would be nice.) Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can add a comment using the "#" at the end of a command: Please refer to the following link http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick and useful answer!

Comment: Please don't link to the ABS. [The `bash` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Comments) is a far better source.

Comment: also, [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CommandsAndArguments) is a good resource with plenty of [FAQs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ) and [common pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls)